# Show/Hide Not Working When Fields Added Using .after () Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add fields using the jQuery `.after()` function, the show/hide functionality does not work on those fields.

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue:

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hnj6ed1y/11/)

The show/hide functionality works on the first row, but does not work on any rows added after that one. I think the code being written after the page has been loaded might be the issue, but I'm not certain. If that's the case, is there a work around other than hard coding a certain amount of rows?

Here's the code I'm working with:

CSS:

```css
#Table {
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
#Table td, #Table th {
    font-size:1em;
    border:1px solid #98bf21;
    padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#Table th {
    font-size:1.4em;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color:#A7C942;
    color:#fff;
}
#Table tr.alt td {
    color:#000;
    background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table style="width: 70%" id="Table" name="Table">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Cause</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select name='report_cause2' id='report_cause2' class="report_cause">
                <option value='default'>-</option>
                <option value='other'>Other, Not Listed</option>
            </select>
            <p class="cause_details">
                <input type="text" name="cause_detail_info" id="cause_detail_info" placeholder="Type cause here" size="48" maxlength="50" class="textbox required" value="" />
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add More" class="button" />
```

jQuery:

```js
var count_2 = 5;
var table_count2 = 1;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.cause_details').hide();
    $('.report_cause').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == 'other') {
            $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').hide();
        }

    });

    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        count_2 = count_2 + 2;
        table_count2 = table_count2 + 1;
        $('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + table_count2 + '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<select name=\"report_cause' + count_2 + '\" id=\"report_cause' + count_2 + '\" class=\"report_cause\">' +
            '<option value=\'default\'>-</option>' +
            '<option value=\'other\'>Other, Not Listed</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '<p class=\"cause_details\">' +
            '<input type=\"text\" name=\"cause_detail_info' + count_2 + '\" id=\"cause_detail_info' + count_2 + '\" placeholder=\"Type cause here\" size=\"48\" maxlength=\"50\" class=\"textbox required\" value=\"\" />' +
            '</p>' +
            '</td></tr>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Elements created after DOM load need to be delegated events, otherwise the DOM has no idea they exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
$('.report_cause').change(function () {
```

Only applies to the `.report_cause` elements that existed when it was called. To handle new elements, you need a delegated handler:

```
$(document).on('change', '.report_cause', function(){
```

Additionally, if you want the new elements initially hidden, modify your output HTML accordingly:

```
'<p class=\"cause_details\" style=\"display:none\">'+
```

```js
var count_2 = 5;
var table_count2 = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.cause_details').hide();
  $(document).on('change', '.report_cause', function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 'other') {
      $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').hide();
    }

  });

  $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    count_2 = count_2 + 2;
    table_count2 = table_count2 + 1;
    $('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td>' + table_count2 + '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<select name=\"report_cause' + count_2 + '\" id=\"report_cause' + count_2 + '\" class=\"report_cause\">' +
      '<option value=\'default\'>-</option>' +
      '<option value=\'other\'>Other, Not Listed</option>' +
      '</select>' +
      '<p class=\"cause_details\" style=\"display:none\">' +
      '<input type=\"text\" name=\"cause_detail_info' + count_2 + '\" id=\"cause_detail_info' + count_2 + '\" placeholder=\"Type cause here\" size=\"48\" maxlength=\"50\" class=\"textbox required\" value=\"\" />' +
      '</p>' +
      '</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

```css
#Table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#Table td,
#Table th {
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #98bf21;
  padding: 3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#Table th {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #A7C942;
  color: #fff;
}
#Table tr.alt td {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #EAF2D3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 70%" id="Table" name="Table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Cause</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <select name='report_cause2' id='report_cause2' class="report_cause">
        <option value='default'>-</option>
        <option value='other'>Other, Not Listed</option>
      </select>
      <p class="cause_details">
        <input type="text" name="cause_detail_info" id="cause_detail_info" placeholder="Type cause here" size="48" maxlength="50" class="textbox required" value="" />
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add More" class="button" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The problem is that when you create a dynamic element, you need to again register change event on `$('.report_cause')`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.cause_details').hide();

    BindChange();

    $('#btnAdd').click(function(){
        count_2 = count_2 + 2;
        table_count2 = table_count2 + 1;
        $('#Table tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+table_count2+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<select name=\"report_cause'+count_2+'\" id=\"report_cause'+count_2+'\" class=\"report_cause\">'+
                '<option value=\'default\'>-</option>'+
                '<option value=\'other\'>Other, Not Listed</option>'+
            '</select>'+
            '<p class=\"cause_details\">'+
                '<input type=\"text\" name=\"cause_detail_info'+count_2+'\" id=\"cause_detail_info'+count_2+'\" placeholder=\"Type cause here\" size=\"48\" maxlength=\"50\" class=\"textbox required\" value=\"\" />'+
            '</p>'+
        '</td></tr>');

        BindChange();
    });
});

function BindChange()
{
    $('.report_cause').bind("change",function(){

    if ($(this).val() == 'other'){
    $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').show();
        }else{
    $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').hide();
        }

    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hnj6ed1y/12/

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: Protip: even correct answers can be downvoted if they are not explained

Answer (score 1):

When you create the elements dynamically, you need to use event delegation to handle the events on them, so based on your jQuery version use `.bind` or `.on` API.

Just change in your code to:

```
$(document).on('change', '.report_cause', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'other') {
            $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.cause_details').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: Protip: even correct answers can be downvoted if they are not explained.